# Using a subquery in a dynamic where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to do the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE workplace IN
    (CASE @param
        WHEN 'a' THEN (SELECT workplace 
                      FROM workPlaceTable
                      WHERE condition1)
        WHEN 'b' THEN (SELECT workplace 
                      FROM workPlaceTable
                      WHERE condition2)
    END)
```

This will always return:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Has anybody an idea how I can realize this without an if and repeating the query?

Comment: Why not just join mytable with workPlaceTable? But you can try TOP 1 in your subquery to see if that helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need the subquery at all, just use a `JOIN` with a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM myTable T1
INNER JOIN workPlaceTable T2 ON T1.workplace = T2.workplace
WHERE (@param = 'a' AND condition1) OR (@param = 'b' AND condition2)
```

If `@param = 'a'` then `condition1` will be evaluated, otherwise `condition2` will be evaluated.

Comment: This will give the same result only if `workplace` is unique in `workPlaceTable`. Naming of table and columns suggests that it might very well be the case.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson Good point. Also, should be `select T1.*`, not `select *`

Comment: take it back what I just said, it worked without subqueries and it got more clear like that.

Comment: @Kiechlus so did you tweak the `JOIN`?

Comment: your approach with the join worked fine. I first thought it wouldn't, because I had unions in the subquery, but I could replace them with another or in the where clause. In the end using joins the query got much easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

> Has anybody an idea how I can realize this without an if and repeating
>   the query?

Something like this could work for you.

```
select *
from myTable
where @Param = 'a' and workplace in (
                                    select workplace 
                                    from workPlaceTable
                                    where condition1
                                    ) or
      @Param = 'b' and workplace in (
                                    select workplace 
                                    from workPlaceTable
                                    where condition2
                                    );
```

Comment: do the `where` clauses need extra brackets around the `a` and `b` parts?

Comment: @Tanner The ones that are there already is of course necessary.

Comment: @Tanner AFAIK, no, because AND has the precedency over OR. Although, sometimes people like putting unnecessary braces for the sake of readability.

Comment: oh ok, is the ordering of the statements sufficient to ensure the logic of the params and subqueries with the `or` will work?

Comment: @Tanner Yes. Your solution is better, but this one will do the job too.

Comment: @user4419802 it's good to know, I guess I'm in the habit of adding the brackets for readability. Find it useful with bracket matching/highlighting in management studio.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on @Allan's answer, a join would look something like this:

```
SELECT myTable.*
FROM myTable
INNER JOIN workPlaceTable ON myTable.workplace = workPlaceTable.workplace AND
(
    (@param = 'a' AND <<condition1>>) OR (@param = 'b' AND <<condition2>>)
)
```

By the way, this question has nothing to do with dynamic-sql.

Comment: ah ok, I always thought SQL is dynamic as soon as there are @params in it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this;

```
SELECT *
  FROM myTable
 WHERE (@param = 'a' and
       workplace in
       (SELECT workplace FROM workPlaceTable WHERE condition1))
    OR (@param = 'b' and
       workplace in
       (SELECT workplace FROM workPlaceTable WHERE condition2))
```

Comment: how is this different from Michael's answer ?